# Background ads click not working whenever clicked on transparent item in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView with one of its item as transparent row to show background DFP ad and this ad is placed behind the RecyclerView in a FrameLayout.

The problem is the ad behind the RecyclerView is not gets clicked even when dispatched touch event to the DFP AdView but its working fine when we use a normal View instead of DFP adview.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

It might be not a perfect solution, but it may work.

You can implement an item click listener in your `RecyclerView`, which will have `onAdClick` (or something like this) method and pass it to the adapter.

```
interface ClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(int position)
    fun onAdClick()
}
```

When an item clicked, check whether it is a regular item or the transparent one, and call `onAdClick` when a transparent item will be clicked.

```
class MyViewHolder(view, val listener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    // ...

    override fun onClick(v:View) {
        if (/* transparent */) {
            listener.onAdClick()
        } else {
            listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Fragment` / `Activity`, that implements `ClickListener`, when `onAdClick` is called just call `view.performClick()` on your AdView.